# Equation Array Nested inside Tabular

Tags: tables, align

This kind of set up where equation array or some align environment, doesn't seem to work inside tabular environment event if math mode is enabled:

Eg : Align

```
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^2 &= 2\\
\frac{3}{4} &=\frac{x}{(1+y)}\\
\end{align*}
```

Eg :  Tabular

```
\begin{tabular}
\alpha &\gamma\\
\beta &\delta
\end{tabular}
```

Eg : Nesting Align inside Tabular - ***doesn't work***

```
Nested
Tabular {
      Align 
}
\newcommand{\test}{\begin{align*}
(1+x)^2 &= 2\\
\frac{3}{4} &=\frac{x}{(1+y)}\\
\end{align*}}

\begin{tabular}
\alpha &\gamma\\
\beta &$\test$
\end{tabular}
```

SOLUTION :
Change align* to aligned environment.

Comment: You can't encase an `align*` environment inside a `tabular` environment. Use an `aligned` environment instead.

Comment: Incidentally, your `tabular` declarations have no chance of being compilable.

Answer (score 3):

On the way, how you doing, no.

- tabular is in "text" mode. You need to change cells in "math" by use of `$ ... $`.
- tabular should have defined column types, for example `\begin{tabular}{cc}`
- including multiline equations is tricky. For example, instead `\begin{align*} ... end{align}` you should write something like `$\begin{aligned} ...\end{aligned}$` from `amsmath` package.

For some concrete solution, prepare (not)working minimal example starting with `\documentclass{...}` necessary packages and encapsulate your code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `aligned` environment is actually provided by the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Yes, i messed with `multlined`. Sorry for wrong information, I will correct this.